# how to calculate entropy on float numbers over a tensor in python keras

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, scipy, entropy

I have been struggling on this and could not get it to work. hope someone can help me with this.

I want to calculate the `entropy` on each row of the `tensor`. **Because my data are float numbers not integers I think I need to use bin_histogram.**

For example a sample of my data is `tensor =[[0.2, -0.1, 1],[2.09,-1.4,0.9]]`

Just for information My model is `seq2seq` and written in `keras` with tensorflow backend.

This is my code so far: I need to correct `rev_entropy`

```
class entropy_measure(Layer):

    def __init__(self, beta,batch, **kwargs):
        self.beta = beta
        self.batch = batch
        self.uses_learning_phase = True
        self.supports_masking = True
        super(entropy_measure, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, x):
        return K.in_train_phase(self.rev_entropy(x, self.beta,self.batch), x)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'beta': self.beta}
        base_config = super(entropy_measure, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def rev_entropy(self, x, beta,batch):

        for i in x:
            i = pd.Series(i)
            p_data = i.value_counts()  # counts occurrence of each value
            entropy = entropy(p_data)  # get entropy from counts
            rev = 1/(1+entropy)
            return rev

        new_f_w_t = x * (rev.reshape(rev.shape[0], 1))*beta

        return new_f_w_t
```

Any input is much appreciated:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*It looks like you have a series of questions that come together on this issue. I'll settle it here.*

You calculate `entropy` in the following form of [`scipy.stats.entropy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html) according to your code:

> scipy.stats.entropy(pk, qk=None, base=None)
>
> Calculate the entropy of a distribution for given probability values.
>
> If only probabilities pk are given, the entropy is calculated as **S =
>   -sum(pk * log(pk), axis=0)**.

Tensorflow does not provide a direct API to calculate `entropy` on each row of the tensor. What we need to do is to implement the above formula.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import entropy

a = [1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,2.2,3.3]
res = entropy(pd.value_counts(a))

_, _, count = tf.unique_with_counts(tf.constant(a))
# [1 2 2 1]
prob = count / tf.reduce_sum(count)
# [0.16666667 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.16666667]
tf_res = -tf.reduce_sum(prob * tf.log(prob))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('scipy version: \n',res)
    print('tensorflow version: \n',sess.run(tf_res))

scipy version: 
 1.329661348854758
tensorflow version: 
 1.3296613488547582
```

Then we need to define a function and achieve `for loop` through `tf.map_fn` in your custom layer according to above code.

```
def rev_entropy(self, x, beta,batch):
    def row_entropy(row):
        _, _, count = tf.unique_with_counts(row)
        prob = count / tf.reduce_sum(count)
        return -tf.reduce_sum(prob * tf.log(prob))

    value_ranges = [-10.0, 100.0]
    nbins = 50
    new_f_w_t = tf.histogram_fixed_width_bins(x, value_ranges, nbins)
    rev = tf.map_fn(row_entropy, new_f_w_t,dtype=tf.float32)

    new_f_w_t = x * 1/(1+rev)*beta

    return new_f_w_t
```

Notes that the hidden layer will not produce a gradient that cannot propagate backwards since `entropy` is calculated on the basis of statistical probabilistic values. Maybe you need to rethink your hidden layer structure.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, you are life saver :), how did you calculate the entropy on real numbers without using bin_histogram? you know what I mean, the problem is that I do not have int numbers they are float that's why I  said differential entropy. I think also differential entropy might not help as the sum up of the variables have to be 1 which is not tru in my case. that's why I need to first use the bin_histogram before calculating the final entropy. Am I make sense?

Comment: Can you please change your answer to include         value_ranges = [-10.0, 100.0]
        nbins = 50
        new_f_w_t = tf.histogram_fixed_width_bins(x, value_ranges, nbins)
        rev = tf.map_fn(row_entropy, new_f_w_t) so I can accept as the accepted answer?

Comment: I have one more question here. after "row_entropy" the shape of tensor changed from (?,20) to (?,) thats why I received an error saying  ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer repeater: expected ndim=2, found ndim=None  . Do you have any idea/input regarding this? Thank U:)

Comment: @sariii `entropy` has nothing to do with real numbers but with their distribution. For example, I chang `[1,2,3,4,2,3]` to `[1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,2.2,3.3]` does not affect the value of `entropy`. What line did your `ValueError` appear in?

Comment: @sariii Note that the hidden layer will not produce a gradient that cannot propagate backwards since the frequency of the statistics required to calculate `entropy`. Maybe you need to rethink your hidden layer structure.

Comment: thank you for replying back, regarding your first comment, for some reason I need to calculate the entropy on numeric data. (Actually to be presice I do not want to differentiate between 1.5 and 1.8 while calculating entropy. I want to put them in the same bin.

Comment: for the second comment, right now I just want it to get it run successfully without thinking about the logic behind it. if I change the custom layer for something else it will be run. Also, the error complaining about the dimension issue, I think if I can fix the dimension issue at least it can get run successfully(I tried some simple thing like multiplying a number to the original tensor and it run successfully. I appreciate it if you look at the code let me know if there is something in which I can fix the dimensionality issue. Really thank you for following my question:)

Comment: And to be honest I did not get this part of your comment "since the frequency of the statistics required to calculate entropy".

Comment: @sariii What I mean is that `entropy` is calculated on the basis of probabilistic values rather than real numbers values. Of course, I will change to `bin_histogram` if you want to put data in the same bin.

Comment: @sariii In addition, I can't reproduce your dimension issue. Can you give more information or code?

Comment: I have updated the post, however, not included the whole code as it becomes lenghty, but the architecture and the error are there. Thnaks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193976/discussion-between-giser-yugang-and-sariii).

Comment: @giser_yugang how do I calculate this (shannon entropy) for 3D inputs (images) which are typically (Batch_Size, Height, Width) for example (1,7,7)

Comment: @SayantanDas I'm sorry to reply so late. I suggest asking a new question and describing it in as much detail as possible so that more people can see it.

Comment: Perhaps it is good to update this a bit from `tf.log` to `tf.math.log`.